# Checking the file extension and viewing the file in angularjs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

I have to check the extension of the file uploaded and view it acoordingly in angularjs.

I get the url of the file in the GET response.

Any help is apprectiated. TIA!

Comment: That GET what return to you, insert it in your question to improve your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this function to fetch file from GET URL

```
function ext(url) {
// Remove everything to the last slash in URL
url = url.substr(1 + url.lastIndexOf("/"));

// Break URL at ? and take first part (file name, extension)
url = url.split('?')[0];

// Sometimes URL doesn't have ? but #, so we should aslo do the same for #
url = url.split('#')[0];

// Now we have only extension
return url;
```

}